# How to set taxonomy in custom plugin?

Tags: wordpress

I am trying to create a plugin, I need a custom post and taxonomy. But it can be accessible in admin side, but the taxonomy is not working on front-end.

This is how I registered the custom post and taxonomy:

```
function post_type_questionnaire()
{
    $labels = array(
        'name' => _x('Questionnaire', 'post type general name'),
        'singular_name' => _x('Questionnaire', 'post type singular name'),
        'add_new' => _x('Add New Question', 'questionnaire'),
        'add_new_item' => __('Add New Questionnaire')
    );

     $args = array(
        'labels' => $labels,
    'public' => true,
    'publicly_queryable' => true,
    'show_ui' => true,
    'query_var' => true,
    'rewrite' => true,
        '_builtin' => false, // It's a custom post type, not built in!
    'capability_type' => 'post',
    'hierarchical' => false,
    'menu_position' => null,
        'supports' => array('title',
                            //'editor',
                            /*'excerpt',
                            'thumbnail',
                            'trackbacks',
                            'custom-fields',
                            'comments',
                            'revisions',
                            'author',
                            'page-attributes'*/
    ));

    register_post_type('questionnaire',$args);

}
add_action('init', 'post_type_questionnaire');



function create_questionnaire_taxanomies(){
    register_taxonomy('qcategories','questionnaire', array(
        'hierarchical'=>true,
        'label'=>'Questionnaire Categories',
        'rewrite' => array( 'slug' => 'questionnaire' )
    ));
}

add_action('init', 'create_questionnaire_taxanomies',0);
```

I am using a shortcode to display it in front-end.

by using the code below it shows all posts

```
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'questionnaire',
    'posts_per_page' => -1,
 );
 $query = new WP_Query($args);
 if ( $query->have_posts() ) { ?>
 <?php while ( $query->have_posts() ) :query->the_post(); ?>
```

But when I try to specify a taxonomy term it doesn't work and this is the code:

```
  $args = array(
    'post_type' => 'questionnaire',
    'posts_per_page' => -1,
    'tax_query' => array(
        array(
            'taxonomy' => 'qcategories',
            'field'    => 'slug',
            'terms'     => $atts["name"]
        )
    )
);
$query = new WP_Query($args);
if ( $query->have_posts() ) { ?>
<?php while ( $query->have_posts() ) : $query->the_post(); ?>
```

When I tried to display the count of post in a template page it show nothing:

```
 $term = get_term( 3, 'qcategories' );
 echo $term->count;
```

This outputs nothing, so I believe that the taxonomy is not registering, can anybody help me to register the taxonomy in my custom plugin. Thanks in advance!

**Edited**

This is the output of $args:

```
array (size=3)
  'post_type' => string 'questionnaire' (length=13)
  'posts_per_page' => int -1
  'tax_query' => 
    array (size=1)
      0 => 
        array (size=3)
          'taxonomy' => string 'qcategories' (length=11)
          'field' => string 'slug' (length=4)
          'terms' => string 'new' (length=3)
```

Comment: taxonomy is showing in backend ?

Comment: @PiyushDhanotiya yes, it is showing in backend

Comment: what is the name of your custom taxonomy and where is the code by which you registered custom taxonomy?

Comment: use get_terms( 3, 'qcategories' );

Comment: @PiyushDhanotiya its not working, qcategories is the custom taxononmy and I have added it above

Comment: @shellysaju You have posts assigned to the terms/taxonomy you are trying to do Query for? Also you sure that             'terms'     => $atts["name"] has the value which is actual slug (for the term you are trying to fetch for)?

Comment: Try to echo or var_dump this $atts["name"] and see if you have correct slug being feeded into the query, or better try by manually giving some slug for the known term in the query and test if query returns results...

Comment: @Mohsin I have tried it, the value is coming correctly

Comment: @shellysaju Looks good the $args you shared, are you sure  you have posts assigned to 'new' term, and also that those posts are published and public.. Also could it be some other filter being applied to the query, try with suppress filters   'suppress_filters' => true

Comment: @Mohsin yes, the posts are published and public and also I have assigned posts to 'new' term.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/135970/discussion-between-shellysaju-and-mohsin).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looked like the code was just fine, as OP discovered there was just a little oversight in the code i.e in the plugin before registering taxonomy there was WordPress template tag `if(is_admin())` which resulted the code work just fine in the Admin Panel, however when it was called in the front-end , there was no Taxonomy available for the `WP_QUERY`

Removing that admin_only if condition, code will just work fine.